# Intellij - how to keep structured search/replace from discarding annotations?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I created a structured search and replace, using this search string:

```
protected $FieldType$ $FieldName$;
```

and this replace string:

```
private $FieldType$ $FieldName$;
```

to replace, for example, this:

```
@Autowired
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

with:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

However, the result is this:

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

That is, the annotation goes away. How do I avoid this? The code base has many protected fields with various annotations, and I want to leave them untouched whatever they are.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If yes, which version of IntelliJ IDEA do you use?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers - Actually, that was a couple projects ago, so I haven't tried it for a while. I don't know if it's still an issue or not.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172046) in Structural Search & Replace.